# Change disabled QIcon tint color

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtstylesheets, qicon, qpalette

I have an application with a custom theme and the disabled icons are to brightly grayed. I would like to change the disabled icon tint color.

Now I know there is a possibility like this:

```
QTableWidgetItem *name = new QTableWidgetItem("test");
QIcon icon("toto.png");
icon.addPixmap(QPixmap("toto.png"),QIcon::Disabled);
name->setIcon(icon);
```

but I have a lot of icons and I wouldn't want to create another set of icons just for the disabled state.

Isn't it possible to change the `QIcon`s' tint color from tinted gray to red or black or any other color?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define your own [`QProxyStyle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qproxystyle.html) and override the [`generatedIconPixmap`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstyle.html#generatedIconPixmap) method.

This method is responsible for generating derived pixmaps for different icon states